Выдает ошибку invalid syntax на двоеточие (в строке if n==5 and n2==5: )
if n==5 and n2==1:
    d=(a**b)+c
    print ("%d**%d+%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d))
    
elif n==5 and n2==2:
    d=(a**b)-c
    print ("%d**%d-%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d))
    
elif n==5 and n2==3:
    d=(a**b)*c
    print ("%d**%d*%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d))
    
elif n==5 and n2==4:
    if с==0:
        print ("Делить на 0 нельзя")
    else:
        d=(a**b)/c
        print ("%d**%d/%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d)
        
if n==5 and n2==5: 
    d=(a**b)**c
    print ("%d**%d**%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d))`


Ошибка выше.....

Почему не привести полный текст ошибки в вопросе?

Ошибка invalid syntax возникает из-за отсутствия закрывающей скобки в строке с операцией деления:
print ("%d**%d/%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d)

Исправь эту строку, добавив закрывающую скобку в конце:
print ("%d**%d/%d=%d" % (a,b,c,d))
#                                ^

